# Extract all arguments of a certain command from a document

Tags: tools, parsing

I have a command `\foo` which takes two arguments and which I use about a hundred times throughout my document (but never within an argument of another instance of `\foo`). I now want to spellcheck every first argument in language A and every second argument in language B. There is a lot of other text in my document, which I do not wish to spellcheck.

The main problem here is parsing all first or second arguments of `\foo`. I could in theory write a script that extracts this, but I suppose somebody has already done this and taken care of all caveats and special cases. So, essentially **I am looking for a tool that allows me to extract all arguments of a certain command throughout a document**. Feeding the output into a spellchecker shouldn’t be a problem.

I am on Linux, so I should be able to get most things running. I prefer solutions that write the arguments to `stdout` or in a file.

The following questions and answers do not solve my problem satisfactorily:

- [How to Spell-Check LaTeX in multiple languages / language variants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20057/28608) – question was specific to a certain editor and only solution so far was to use external files (which is not feasible for me and would require parsing anyway to set it up automatically).
- [Extract all emphasized words from latex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79928/28608) – [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79929/28608) would probably work, but is aimed at collecting and printing inside a single document and thus probably overly complicated for my needs.
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193097/28608 – This question also aims at addressing the problem in TeX, as far as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a Perl script (or whatever scripting language you like most) is more efficient. But it's possible to do it also in TeX.

Taking Werner's input as model, here's a way for writing out two files, containing the first and second arguments to `\foo`, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{langA}{red!30}
\colorlet{langB}{blue!30}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  % the original definition (supply yours)
  \textcolor{langA}{#1}--\textcolor{langB}{#2}%
  % the added part
  \write\langAout{\detokenize{#1}}\write\langBout{\detokenize{#2}}%
}
\newwrite\langAout
\newwrite\langBout
\immediate\openout\langAout=\jobname-a.out
\immediate\openout\langBout=\jobname-b.out

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \foo{consectetur}{adipiscing} elit. Phasellus elementum 
urna quis \foo{mi}{fermentum}, sit amet congue ex lobortis. Vivamus vulputate turpis 
neque, nec rutrum magna tempor ac. \foo{Sed}{pulvinar} tristique tempor. Sed venenatis 
tincidunt nunc, sit amet dictum eros. Proin sed consequat turpis. \foo{Nulla}{ut} mauris 
lacinia \foo{lacus}{sollicitudin} imperdiet at ut lorem. Sed in efficitur ante. Nulla 
scelerisque, \foo{massa}{pharetra} dictum vestibulum, lectus diam elementum ante, id 
ultricies lectus tellus sed turpis. Phasellus \foo{nec}{maximus} dolor. Cras vehicula 
tincidunt quam finibus fringilla. Maecenas eget leo nec quam \foo{venenatis}{sagittis}. 
\foo{Etiam}{eget} est id mauris mollis egestas nec eget sapien. Suspendisse aliquet massa 
at urna mattis fermentum. \foo{Quisque}{quis} sem turpis. Donec viverra ornare leo, sit 
amet consectetur lacus eleifend a. Fusce \foo{elementum}{sem} volutpat ante mattis luctus.

Proin \foo{volutpat}{justo} quis fringilla viverra. Integer erat lectus, facilisis at 
posuere a, maximus at libero. \foo{Phasellus}{malesuada} tincidunt turpis quis condimentum. 
Ut eget nibh id lorem vulputate sagittis. Pellentesque \foo{habitant}{morbi} tristique 
senectus et netus et malesuada \foo{fames}{ac} turpis egestas. Etiam et malesuada magna. 
Pellentesque dictum \foo{blandit}{est}, at condimentum nunc volutpat a. Donec venenatis 
orci sapien, eu placerat ligula \foo{pulvinar}{eget}.

\end{document}
```

If the main file is named `test.tex`, you'll get two files named `test-a.out` and `test-b.out`:

#### `test-a.out`

```
consectetur
mi
Sed
Nulla
lacus
massa
nec
venenatis
Etiam
Quisque
elementum
volutpat
Phasellus
habitant
fames
blandit
pulvinar
```

#### `test-b.out`

```
adipiscing
fermentum
pulvinar
ut
sollicitudin
pharetra
maximus
sagittis
eget
quis
sem
justo
malesuada
morbi
ac
est
eget
```

Comment: Accepting the answer as it extracts the contents into a file and thus makes further handling with a spell checker easier (in contrast to Werner’s answer).

Answer (score 3):

The following is an adaptation of [Extract all emphasized words from LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79929/5764), now only for two arguments. The first arguments are stored in `\firstfoo`, while the second arguments are stored in `\secondfoo`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  % <your original definition>
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstfoo}{}
\newcommand{\secondfoo}{}
\renewcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \textit{#1} \textbf{#2}% Just for display
  \g@addto@macro{\firstfoo}{#1\space}% Add first argument to \firstfoo
  \g@addto@macro{\secondfoo}{#2\space}% Add second argument to \secondfoo
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \foo{consectetur}{adipiscing} elit. Phasellus elementum 
urna quis \foo{mi}{fermentum}, sit amet congue ex lobortis. Vivamus vulputate turpis 
neque, nec rutrum magna tempor ac. \foo{Sed}{pulvinar} tristique tempor. Sed venenatis 
tincidunt nunc, sit amet dictum eros. Proin sed consequat turpis. \foo{Nulla}{ut} mauris 
lacinia \foo{lacus}{sollicitudin} imperdiet at ut lorem. Sed in efficitur ante. Nulla 
scelerisque, \foo{massa}{pharetra} dictum vestibulum, lectus diam elementum ante, id 
ultricies lectus tellus sed turpis. Phasellus \foo{nec}{maximus} dolor. Cras vehicula 
tincidunt quam finibus fringilla. Maecenas eget leo nec quam \foo{venenatis}{sagittis}. 
\foo{Etiam}{eget} est id mauris mollis egestas nec eget sapien. Suspendisse aliquet massa 
at urna mattis fermentum. \foo{Quisque}{quis} sem turpis. Donec viverra ornare leo, sit 
amet consectetur lacus eleifend a. Fusce \foo{elementum}{sem} volutpat ante mattis luctus.

Proin \foo{volutpat}{justo} quis fringilla viverra. Integer erat lectus, facilisis at 
posuere a, maximus at libero. \foo{Phasellus}{malesuada} tincidunt turpis quis condimentum. 
Ut eget nibh id lorem vulputate sagittis. Pellentesque \foo{habitant}{morbi} tristique 
senectus et netus et malesuada \foo{fames}{ac} turpis egestas. Etiam et malesuada magna. 
Pellentesque dictum \foo{blandit}{est}, at condimentum nunc volutpat a. Donec venenatis 
orci sapien, eu placerat ligula \foo{pulvinar}{eget}.

\verb|\firstfoo|: {\itshape \firstfoo}

\verb|\secondfoo|: {\bfseries \secondfoo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general scheme:

```
\newif\iflanguageA
\def\foo#1#2{\iflanguageA your action on #1\else your action on #1 \fi}
```

With usage:

```
\languageAtrue

\foo12, 

\languageAfalse

\foo12.
```

You have conditional `\iflanguageA` (the name is to be chosen) and Boolean values `\languageAtrue` and `\languageAfalse`.

Comment: This describes how to create such a command, but not how to perform a spellcheck on all of its first or second arguments. I thus fail to see how this answers my question.